# Error message while using "highfrequency" package in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to use the functions medRV and makeReturns in the package "highfrequency". This worked fine until a couple of weeks ago. Now, while trying to use either of the two functions, I get the following error messages (already while typing makeReturns() - I don't even need to press enter, for the error message to show up):

1: In args(makeReturns) : restarting interrupted promise evaluation

2: In args(makeReturns) : internal error -3 in R_decompress1

I've tried to uninstall the package "highfrequency" via

> remove.packages("highfrequency")

but when I re-install it, I still get the same error message.

Even without re-installing it, and just entering

> library("highfrequency")

I get the same error message, when attempting to type

> makeReturns()

or

> medRV()

I use the R-version

R.Version()$version.string
[1] "R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)"

How can I fix this?
Any help is very much appreciated!

EDIT:

As mentioned above, if I just type "make.Returns()" or "medRV()" I get the error message reported before, even without hitting enter. If I do hit enter, one more error message pops up saying:

Error: lazy-load database 'P' is corrupt

Comment: WAG: download latest `highfrequency` package and reinstall?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is the latest version not automatically installed when I use "install.packages("highfrequency")"?

Comment: Here's how I'd approach (1) use `.libPaths()` go there and manually delete highfrequency.  (2) then reinstall but choose a different repo location.  (3) If that doesn't work I'd try opening a vanilla session of R and try loading/reinstalling.  (4) last a reinstall of R may be in order.  I think `sessionInfo()` may give us useful information here.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I've tried to do the first thing you suggested but it didn't work. However, the output of sessionInfo() looks interesting. In fact it says:
WARNING:
In FUN(c("chron", "glmnet", "timeDate", "Matrix", "highfrequency",  :
  DESCRIPTIN of package 'highfrequency' is missing or corrupted.

[I translated it from german] Does this help?

Comment: I reinstalled it in the location with all other pckgs. And now I get:

> sessionInfo()
R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)

locale:
[1] de_CH.UTF-8/de_CH.UTF-8/de_CH.UTF-8/C/de_CH.UTF-8/de_CH.UTF-8

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] chron_2.3-45      glmnet_1.9-5      timeDate_3010.98  Matrix_1.1-0      highfrequency_0.2
[6] xts_0.9-7         zoo_1.7-11       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.0.2      lattice_0.20-27 tools_3.0.2